# Big query- get last date of every month in a year

Tags: google-bigquery

Iam trying to extract only the last dates of  every month in a year.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM 
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-04-30', '2027-03-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS example
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

I am getting

```
1   2018-04-30
2   2018-05-30
3   2018-06-30
4   2018-07-30
5   2018-08-30
6   2018-09-30
7   2018-10-30
8   2018-11-30
9   2018-12-30
10  2019-01-30
```

EXPECTATION:

```
31/01/2013
28/02/2013
31/03/2013
30/04/2013
31/05/2013
30/06/2013
31/07/2013
31/08/2013
30/09/2013
31/10/2013
30/11/2013
31/12/2013
31/01/2014
28/02/2014
31/03/2014
30/04/2014
31/05/2014
30/06/2014
31/07/2014
31/08/2014
30/09/2014
31/10/2014
30/11/2014
31/12/2014
31/01/2015
28/02/2015
```

Comment: I'm probably wrong about this, but I'm assuming `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` is only incrementing the month without being aware of the end of the month

Comment: yes guess so. its not identifying the exact last date ..

Answer (score 3):

You could generate an array of the first day of each month and then subtract one day to get the last day of the previous month:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(example, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-05-1', '2027-04-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS example
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(example, MONTH) last_day_of_month
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-04-30', '2027-03-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS example
```

Comment: great.. this works! was not aware of 'LAST_DAY' function in BQ.. Thank you.